# JavaScript How do get differents coordinates clientX and clientX

Tags: javascript

I am trying to reproduce a paint api with canvas. I need to get two coordinates to draw a rectangle but it seems that JavaScript keeps only one coordinate.

here is my code:

```
var x_1;
var y_1;
var x_2;
var y_2;
var tab_coord;

function coord(evt) {
x_1 = evt.clientX;
y_1 = evt.clientY;
console.log("coord x_1 :" + x_1 + "y :" + y_1);
tab_coord={'x_1': x_1, 'x_2':y_1};


canvas.addEventListener('click', second_coord);
}
function second_coord(evt) {
console.log(tab_coord);
x_2 = evt.clientX;
y_2 = evt.clientY;

console.log("coord x_2:" + x_2 + "y :" + y_2);
}
```

If in the `console.log("coord x_1 :" + x_1 + "y :" + y_1)` I have the first coordinate, JS don't keep it in the `tab_coord`. Thus the `console.log(tab_coord)` indicate the coordinate of `x_2` and `y_2` and not `x_1`, `y_1` as I wanted to.

Comment: the first function coord is called like that :    canvas.addEventListener('click', second_coord);

Comment: It looks like tab_coord isn't being set correctly.  The first property being set is x_1, the second is x_2.  Should this be y_1 instead of x_2 for the second property?

Comment: yes Skunkman I made a mistake the key is wrong it should have been 'y_1':y_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should not add the eventListener on each click, btw you also need only one click handler to handle different actions.**

**Check this out:**

Creates canvas fullscreen, defines an undefined x1 and y1, add an eventlistener to the canvas on load which executes the shape based on the `shape` value, shapes contains then the various types of shapeFunctions.

to create a rect you need to subtract the x1 to the x2 and y1 to the y2

x2,y2 are not needed if you use a two click function.

```
var C=document.createElement('canvas'),
    c=C.getContext('2d'),
    x1,
    y1,
    shape='rect';
    C.width=window.innerWidth;
    C.height=window.innerHeight;
    C.style.cssText='position:fixed;top:0;left:0;';
    document.body.appendChild(C);
    C.addEventListener('click',handler,false);

function handler(e){
 shapes[shape](e);
}

shapes={    
 rect:function(e){
  x1? // with this simple check you can't use 0 as it returns false.
  (c.rect(x1,y1,e.clientX-x1,e.clientY-y1),c.stroke(),x1=y1=false):
  (x1=e.clientX,y1=e.clientY);
 }
 //Add more shape functions here.Or fill whatever....
}
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/yY8EX/

**Demo with circle**

http://jsfiddle.net/yY8EX/2/

If you don't understand something or have any other questions just ask.